# check progress of process in oracle, using an array of variables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

thanks for your help this days and I hope I've helping at least one person, but I'm not here for congrat and stuff.

I've a problem when I try to check the status of some process on the DB

I've make a query:

```
DECLARE 
CLAVES varchar(12);
FECHA   date;

BEGIN

FECHA    := TO_DATE('16/10/2015','DD/MM/YYYY');
FOR KEYS IN (
        SELECT  SKEY,
                SUBSTR(RPAD(COD.SCOMMAND,43),41)    PROD 
        FROM    INSUDB.BATCH_JOB COD,
                INSUDB.BATCH_PROCESS PRO
        WHERE   COD.NUSERCODE = '3345'
        AND     COD.NBATCH = PRO.NBATCH
        AND     COD.NUSERSUBMIT = COD.NUSERCODE
        AND     TRUNC(COD.DSUBMIT) = TO_DATE ('16/10/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        AND     PRO.SCODISPL    = 'VIL7002'
        ORDER BY COD.DSUBMIT ASC 

    )LOOP
        CLAVES :=   TRIM(TO_CHAR(KEYS.SKEY));

        BEGIN
            SELECT  '01 - EJEC' " ", 
                    NPRODUCT PRODUCTO, 
                    COUNT(*) CONTAR,
                    TO_CHAR(NVL(TRUNC(MOD((MAX(DCOMPDATE) - MIN(DCOMPDATE))*24,24 )),0)) ||' HRS. '|| 
                    TO_CHAR(NVL(TRUNC(MOD((MAX(DCOMPDATE) - MIN(DCOMPDATE))*24*60,60)),0)) ||' MIN. '|| 
                    TO_CHAR(NVL(TRUNC(MOD((MAX(DCOMPDATE) - MIN(DCOMPDATE))*24*60*60,60)),0)) ||' SEG.' TIEMPO,
                    MIN(DCOMPDATE) ,
                    MAX(DCOMPDATE) 
            FROM    TIMETMP.TMP_VIL7002
            WHERE   SKEY = CLAVES
            AND     NSTATUS = 1
            group by nproduct
            UNION
            SELECT  '02 - PEND' COL, 
                    null, 
                    COUNT(*), 
                    NULL, 
                    NULL, 
                    NULL
            FROM    TIMETMP.TMP_VIL7002
            WHERE   SKEY = CLAVES
            AND     NSTATUS <> 1
            UNION
            SELECT  '03 - ERR ' COL, 
                    null,
                    COUNT(*), 
                    NULL, 
                    NULL, 
                    NULL
            FROM    TIMETMP.TMP_VIL7002
            WHERE   SKEY = CLAVES
            AND     NSTATUS = 3
            UNION
            SELECT  '04 - TOTAL' COL, 
                    null, 
                    COUNT(*), 
                    NULL, 
                    NULL, 
                    NULL
            FROM    TIMETMP.TMP_VIL7002
            WHERE   SKEY = CLAVES;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

this only give me the next error message

```
END;
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: línea 24, columna 17:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what the message says. If you execute a select statement in PLSQL, you have to do something with the result. You can make a for loop to iterate over it (like you do with the first query), or add an into clause in which you specify a PLSQL variable for each of the columns you have in the query. That is what PLSQL expects if you execute a statement like your inner SQL statement.

As it is now, it would just execute the big inner query without doing anything with its results. And since that is silly, PLSQL doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you write a `SELECT` statement in PL/SQL, you should actually use a `SELECT INTO` statement so that result has somewhere to go.

You can see how to make a `SELECT INTO` here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm

Answer (score 0):

so, I finally resolve my problem, using this query and don´t use procedure

```
SELECT  SKEY,
    SUBSTR(RPAD(COD.SCOMMAND,43),41)    PROD,
    SUBSTR(RPAD(COD.SCOMMAND,67),66)||'/'||SUBSTR(RPAD(COD.SCOMMAND,65),64)||'/'||SUBSTR(RPAD(COD.SCOMMAND,63),60)    FECHA, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TIMETMP.TMP_VIL7002 TMP WHERE TMP.SKEY = COD.SKEY AND NSTATUS = 1) EJECUTADOS,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TIMETMP.TMP_VIL7002 TMP WHERE TMP.SKEY = COD.SKEY AND NSTATUS <> 1) PENDIENTES,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TIMETMP.TMP_VIL7002 TMP WHERE TMP.SKEY = COD.SKEY AND NSTATUS = 3) ERRORES,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TIMETMP.TMP_VIL7002 TMP WHERE TMP.SKEY = COD.SKEY ) TOTAL,
    (SELECT MIN(DCOMPDATE) FROM TIMETMP.TMP_VIL7002 TMP WHERE TMP.SKEY = COD.SKEY ) INICIO,
    (SELECT MAX(DCOMPDATE) FROM TIMETMP.TMP_VIL7002 TMP WHERE TMP.SKEY = COD.SKEY ) TERMINO  
FROM    INSUDB.BATCH_JOB COD,
    INSUDB.BATCH_PROCESS PRO
WHERE   COD.NUSERCODE = '3345'
AND     COD.NBATCH = PRO.NBATCH
AND     COD.NUSERSUBMIT = COD.NUSERCODE
AND     TRUNC(COD.DSUBMIT) = TO_DATE ('18/10/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') -- unico parametro a cambiar es la fecha de ejecucion
AND     PRO.SCODISPL    = 'VIL7002'
ORDER BY COD.DSUBMIT ASC
```